# temporary root for HTC Desire HD

Tags: rooting, htc-desire-hd

I would have a temporary (permanent not required) root to install few apps which need root in my HTC desire HD with Android 2.3.5. I have no idea status of S-OFF , I suppose is enabled.

Is there any solution which works without dowgrading from 2.3.5 and without losing data or formatting my SD card (something similar to Visionary which worked with Froyo only) ?

Other information I know about my phone

ACE PVT SHIP S-ON RL , HBOOT-2.00.0027  , MICROP-0438 , RADIO-26.14.0.28_M , 
eMMC-boot  , sep 7 2011,19:06:24

## Paid support offer

My promise/NO JOKE : I can offer $25.00 via paypal for anyone offering me a WORKING solution. Also If you have a way to have permament root in a similar way (without dowgrading Android, WITHOUT losing data , WITHOUT formatting my SD card, WITHOUT backup and restore data) I can offer $50.00 via paypal.

Thank you
Graziano

Comment: Is your bootloader unlocked?

Comment: I suppose no, how can I know it ?

Comment: I have this data , if it can help
ACE PVT SHIP S-ON RL , HBOOT-2.00.0027 , MICROP-0438 , RADIO-26.14.0.28_M , eMMC-boot , sep 7 2011,19:06:24

Comment: Usually, the bootloader is locked by default. If you didn't unlock it sometimes via htcdev.com, it is most likely locked. In this case, I can't guide you if you don't want to loose data, because of security the bootloader-unlock-procedere will perform a factory reset on the phone. Maybe there is another way, I don't know.

Comment: The htcdev.com procedure requires losing data , which I would avoid. BTW I don't understand why temproot was available in froyo and why it's no more possible in 2.3.5 .

Comment: there is an app which claims to be able to do what I am asking, could it be true ?  http://batakang.com/apps.php

Comment: none of these three apps in the link is nearly the one you're looking for. There is one which unroots everything and two which need an already rooted device.